# I want to Layered navigation with following Result

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have used magento layered navigation but its to lazy work. when i selected any one attribute from layer its hide all other. and just display **clear all** link.

[image]

[image]

but i want to this type on result. display all attribute as it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change in core file rewrite it.

In function **applyFilterToCollection** in

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php**

Replace:

```
$tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx';
```

With:

```
$tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx_'.$value;
```

In apply in
**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php**

Comment it or delete the following line:

```
$this->_items = array();
```

to

```
//$this->_items = array();
```

Add the following method to

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php**

```
public function isSelected()
{
  $selected = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest()->getParam($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar());
  if( $selected == $this->getValue() )
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

For Price Filter,

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php**

```
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_RANGE_CALCULATION) == self::RANGE_CALCULATION_IMPROVED) {
            return $this->_getCalculatedItemsData();
        } elseif ($this->getInterval()) {
            return array();
        }

        $range      = $this->getPriceRange();
        $dbRanges   = $this->getRangeItemCounts($range);
        $data       = array();

        if (!empty($dbRanges)) {
            $lastIndex = array_keys($dbRanges);
            $lastIndex = $lastIndex[count($lastIndex) - 1];

            foreach ($dbRanges as $index => $count) {
                $fromPrice = ($index == 1) ? '' : (($index - 1) * $range);
                $toPrice = ($index == $lastIndex) ? '' : ($index * $range);

                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderRangeLabel($fromPrice, $toPrice),
                    'value' => $fromPrice . '-' . $toPrice,
                    'count' => $count,
                );
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Change to:

```
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_RANGE_CALCULATION) == self::RANGE_CALCULATION_IMPROVED) {
            return $this->_getCalculatedItemsData();
        } 
       //elseif ($this->getInterval()) {
         //   return array();
        //}

        $range      = $this->getPriceRange();
        $dbRanges   = $this->getRangeItemCounts($range);
        $data       = array();

        if (!empty($dbRanges)) {
            $lastIndex = array_keys($dbRanges);
            $lastIndex = $lastIndex[count($lastIndex) - 1];

            foreach ($dbRanges as $index => $count) {
                $fromPrice = ($index == 1) ? '' : (($index - 1) * $range);
                $toPrice = ($index == $lastIndex) ? '' : ($index * $range);

                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderRangeLabel($fromPrice, $toPrice),
                    'value' => $fromPrice . '-' . $toPrice,
                    'count' => $count,
                );
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: hi. its working but not according to my question. i want to display all attribute as it is. but with your solution only display selected attribute.

Comment: Not selected it displays all attribute. I have checked it, its working for me.